# FDTD with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

when I wrote my equations  to be solved in numpy array form, python calculate it much faster.
for example this program is in pure python and takes **560 seconds** to run:

```
    from numpy import zeros
from scipy import weave

dx = 0.1
dy = 0.1
dx2 = dx*dx
dy2 = dy*dy

def py_update(u):
    nx, ny = u.shape
    for i in xrange(1,nx-1):
        for j in xrange(1, ny-1):
            u[i,j] = ((u[i+1, j] + u[i-1, j]) * dy2 +
                      (u[i, j+1] + u[i, j-1]) * dx2) / (2*(dx2+dy2))

def calc(N, Niter=100, func=py_update, args=()):
    u = zeros([N, N])
    u[0] = 1
    for i in range(Niter):
        func(u,*args)
    return u
```

but in numpy mode, it takes only **2.24 seconds**

```
def num_update(u):
    u[1:-1,1:-1] = ((u[2:,1:-1]+u[:-2,1:-1])*dy2 + 
                    (u[1:-1,2:] + u[1:-1,:-2])*dx2) / (2*(dx2+dy2))
```

Now I want to apply this to a FDTD problem, i have this two equations:

```
Ey[j+1,i]=Ey[j,i]-Alpha(Hz[j+1/2,i+1/2]-Hz[j+1/2,i-1/2])

Hz[j+1/2,i+1/2]=Hz[j-1/2]-Beta[Ey[j,i+1]-Ey[j,i]]
```

Ey & Hz are the electric and magnetic field components in 1D space.
and i want to write it in numpy array form like above.

Comment: You can use Numba to JIT the calculation function.

Comment: You could take a look into FEniCs (http://fenicsproject.org/). Though it's designed for FEM Problems, there efficient ways to to differentiation.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: last part is the question! how to write that two equations in numpy?